# Discord.py library sending message upon member update

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

this is how I've already tried getting the message channel that I would presume the discord server uses for this bot, from having used its other functionality:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global message_channel
    message_channel = message.channel
```

I want to send a message saying goodbye to users when they go offline using this function

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(str(before.status), str(after.status))
    if str(before.status) == "online" and str(after.status) == "offline": 
        print("someone went offline")
        try: await message_channel.send(f'Goodbye, {after.user}')
        except: print('failed to send goodbye message')
```

I'd appreciate either finding a way to make this work (since currently nothing at all prints from the on_member_update() function, or if I could get the channel that the last message was sent to from the bot (meaning this would only be in place once the bot is used at least once)

Comment: Is there any error/traceback?

Comment: The event just doesn't get triggered, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make a own channel for the goodbye messages or define a extra channel for it. This would look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    pass#your code here



@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(str(before.status), str(after.status))
    if str(before.status) == "online" and str(after.status) == "offline": 
        channel = cliet.get_channel(channelId)
        print("someone went offline")
        try: 
            await channel.send(f'Goodbye, {after.user}')
        except: 
            print('failed to send goodbye message')
```

If you want to write the goodbye message in the channel the user last wrote in you can simply make a txt with the users and their last channels. You can also do this with json. If you do it in on_message you get the channel that was last typed in by anyone on the server OR in the dms of the bot. So if userXYZ wrote the BOT "Hello World" via DM and then another user userABC went offline the BOT will send userXYZ a Goodbye message via DM.